# Altering tuples within a list - is this the best way?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples this form:

```
my_list = [(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]
```

I want to do something to the second member of each tuple. It's fine if I need to make a new list, though I won't need the old one.

This is what I am doing now:

```
new_list = []
for x,y in my_list:
    new.list.append((x,my_function(y)))
```

This works but feels clunky, is it the best/most pythonic/fastest way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to generate new tuples:

```
new_list = [(x, my_function(y)) for x, y in my_list]
```

This comes down to the same as your version, but avoids the repeated `.append()` calls and builds the list in one go.

Comment: Thanks. Still haven't gotten the hang of the do something, for something, in something syntax...this'll be my first use.

Comment: Looks like I'm last to edit, so I'll be the first to delete n_n!

Comment: @user2063292: Learning how to manually translate list comprehensions into explicit loops is very helpful while you're learning. See [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/comprehensions-for-dummies.html) for help with that. Once you get enough practice, the abstraction "clicks" in your head, and you'll find the comprehensions are actually _easier_ to read.

Answer (score 4):

using a list comprehension is usually cleaner:

```
[(x, function(y)) for x,y in my_list]
```

you can then write it back onto `my_list` or give it a new variable name if you choose:

```
my_list = [(x, function(y)) for x,y in my_list]
```

Or even do a slice assignment to replace `my_list` in place:

```
my_list[:] = [(x, function(y)) for x,y in my_list]
```

Comment: Neat. wish I could check both answers.